# Writing to specific position in a file

Tags: c++, file

I have

```
fstream output;
output.open(fname, ios::out | ios::trunc); //file
for (int i=0; i<flength; i++)
    output.put('1');
```

I want to overwrite different length of data to different locations in the file. Data is characters.

Lets say there is `111111111111111111111111111111111`, I want to write

```
11   111111333111!!!!!!1    11441111
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [seekp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/seekp/) to set the position of the put pointer and write at the specific position in the file, e.g.

```
 output.seekp(10);
 output.put('!');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `seekp()` to set the writing position in the file stream.

Comment: I tried this, but after using it for second iteration i get missng characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "insert" things in the middle of the file - the only inplace operations you can do is writing the exact same amount of bytes that you are trying to overwrite, i.e. writing without changing the length of the file. If you need to write a string of different length (as in your example) you have to rewrite the whole file from the point where you ended your write operation (store original in a buffer and rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

Check out `ostream::seekp`, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/seekp/).  Position the file-pointer to the desired location before writing.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is to rewrite the whole file into another file after making required changes.

```
std::ifstream fin("yourfile.txt");
remove("yourfile.txt");
```

Copy the stream before removing your file. This can help you preserve the name of the file.